# canvas stretch while resizing page

Tags: canvas, jcanvas

I have a canvas (with width and height) and I use JCanvas to draw on it.
I want that if I resize the browser - the canvas will be stretch (increase or decrease). I want that also the background image will be resize and everything on it will be too.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out that JCanvas has its own function for that 
http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs.php?p=scaleCanvas